# Making a JSON Object as Google Maps API Call in React Native

Tags: google-maps, react-native

I wanted to call GoogleMapsAPI and get results with specified origin and destination. However, I cannot pass the result of the api call immediately because it returns the result after I do assign operation. I wanted to pass the result immediately but I couldn't find any proper solution. Here is my fetch code for API.

```
class RouteSelection extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.fetchApi = this.fetchApi.bind(this);
  this.fetchDef = this.fetchDef.bind(this);
  this.fetchFewer = this.fetchFewer.bind(this);
  this.fetchLess = this.fetchLess.bind(this);
  this.fetchBestGuessTraffic = this.fetchBestGuessTraffic.bind(this);
  this.fetchPessimisticTraffic = this.fetchPessimisticTraffic.bind(this);
  this.fetchOptimisticTraffic = this.fetchOptimisticTraffic.bind(this);
  this.calcRoutes = this.calcRoutes.bind(this);
  this.state = {
    origin: "",
    destination: "",
    arrival_time: "",
    def_data: [],
    f_data: [],
    l_data: [],
    best_guess: [],
    pessimistic_guess: [],
    optimistic_guess: [],
  };
}

fetchDef(){

  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + this.state.origin + "&destination=" + this.state.destination +"&key= API_KEY&mode=transit&alternatives=true", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.setState({ def_data: responseData.routes }))
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Network Request Failed',
      'Server cannot retrieve users from server. Please chech the internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK' }
      ]
    )
  });
}

fetchLess(){

  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + this.state.origin + "&destination=" + this.state.destination +"&key= API_KEY&mode=transit&alternatives=true&transit_routing_preference=less_walking", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.setState({ l_data: responseData.routes }))
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Network Request Failed',
      'Server cannot retrieve users from server. Please chech the internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK' }
      ]
    )
  });
}

fetchFewer(){

  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + this.state.origin + "&destination=" + this.state.destination +"&key= API_KEY&mode=transit&alternatives=true&transit_routing_preference=fewer_transfers", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.setState({ f_data: responseData.routes }))

  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Network Request Failed',
      'Server cannot retrieve users from server. Please chech the internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK' }
      ]
    )
  });
}

fetchBestGuessTraffic(){

  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + this.state.origin + "&destination=" + this.state.destination +"&key= API_KEY&mode=transit&alternatives=true&traffic_model=best_guess", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.setState({ best_guess: responseData.routes }))
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Network Request Failed',
      'Server cannot retrieve users from server. Please chech the internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK' }
      ]
    )
  });
}

fetchPessimisticTraffic(){

  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + this.state.origin + "&destination=" + this.state.destination +"&key= API_KEY&mode=transit&alternatives=true&traffic_model=pessimistic", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.setState({ pessimistic_guess: responseData.routes }))
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Network Request Failed',
      'Server cannot retrieve users from server. Please chech the internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK' }
      ]
    )
  });
}

fetchOptimisticTraffic(){

  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + this.state.origin + "&destination=" + this.state.destination +"&key= API_KEY&mode=transit&alternatives=true&traffic_model=optimistic", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => this.setState({ optimistic_guess: responseData.routes }))
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Network Request Failed',
      'Server cannot retrieve users from server. Please chech the internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK' }
      ]
    )
  });
}

fetchApi() {

  this.fetchFewer();
  this.fetchLess();
  this.fetchDef();
  this.fetchBestGuessTraffic();
  this.fetchOptimisticTraffic();
  this.fetchPessimisticTraffic();

}

calcRoutes(){

 console.log("Fewer Transfers ");
 console.log(this.state.f_data);
 console.log("Less Walking ");
 console.log(this.state.l_data);
 console.log("Default ");
 console.log(this.state.def_data);
 console.log("Best Guess Traffic ");
 console.log(this.state.best_guess);
 console.log("Optimistic Guess Traffic ");
 console.log(this.state.optimistic_guess);
 console.log("Pessimistic Guess Traffic ");
 console.log(this.state.pessimistic_guess);

 this.props.navigator.push({
   id: 'UserPref',
   name: 'UserPref',
 });


}
```

Comment: from where are you calling calcRoutes() ?

Comment: @Codesingh I call calcRoutes() function from another method fetchApi() which is a function that calling from a button with " onPress={() => this.fetchApi() }> "

Comment: Are you wanting to pass `optimistic_guess` into the next route?

Comment: According to me use callback... if you can provide me the code i will help you to implement callbacks...

Comment: @BradBumbalough I want to assign the response (json object) of Google Maps API call to a state that I have defined as "optimistic_guess" and process in another method (like extracting duration of the route, optimistic_guess.routes.duration)

Comment: @Codesingh I will happy to. How can I provide? At here or e-mail wise.

Comment: please provide me the full code so that it would become easier for me to understand..

Comment: here only just from where are you calling and all

Comment: @Codesingh I have edited the code above, thanks for your help...

Comment: @ua_cs sorry for the delay, have a look at my answer and in case you have any doubt feel free to ping me ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code implies that there are many asynchronous calls. In order to get defined values in logs you need to implement either `async/await` , `callback` or .then() i.e resolve promise.

we will implement callback in the above code snippet:-

I will do one for you and rest is for practice...

wherever you are calling  onPress={() => this.fetchApi(function(data){calcRoutes(data)}) }  just pass a callback..and instead of calling calcRoutes() function from different method call it here because you don't know when will response come.

After that :

```
fetchApi(callback) {

  this.fetchFewer(function(data){callback(data)});    
}

fetchFewer(callback){

  fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + this.state.origin + "&destination=" + this.state.destination +"&key= API_KEY&mode=transit&alternatives=true&transit_routing_preference=fewer_transfers", {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {this.setState({ f_data: responseData.routes }) callback(responseData.routes)})

  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Network Request Failed',
      'Server cannot retrieve users from server. Please chech the internet connection',
      [
        { text: 'OK' }
      ]
    )
  });
}
```

This is how callback works...

Cheers :)

Comment: thank you so much for your contribution, I have one question about the render function that performs onPress operation. Do I have to implement it in a way of onPress={() => this.fetchApi(function(data){calcRoutes(data)}) } or can I let the code with onPress={() => this.fetchApi()}. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: I wrote in that way because it seems there is no method in your question that is calling calcRoutes() so i wrote there and i think that's the right way..is it working for you ..?

Comment: You are absolutely right. One last question for now, I got a syntax error at the line of " .then( (responseData) => { this.setState({ def_data: responseData.routes }) callback(responseData.routes) } )" I couldn't figure it out, can you help me in advance? Thank you really much for your help

Comment: just putting semicolon after this.setstate may work and that's all for the day as i am going to sleep and help will be continued ".then( (responseData) => { this.setState({ def_data: responseData.routes }); callback(responseData.routes) } )"...:)

Comment: Thank you so much!